# solcover fail to generate test coverage with my simple add contract

Tags: test-coverage, solidity, truffle

I want to use solcover to generate test coverage of my contract.

`https://github.com/JoinColony/solcover`

I test it with the simple one:

```
contract Add {
    function Add() {
    }
    function sum(uint x, uint y) returns (uint) {
        return (x+y);
    }
}
```

And here is my test code:

```
contract('Add', function(accounts) {
  it("should return 5 when add 2 and 3", function() {
    var add = Add.deployed();
    return add.sum.call(2,3).then(function(res){
      assert.equal(res.valueOf(), 5, "add result is 5");
    });   
  });
});
```

But there are some errs when compile it.

`Add.sol:2:1: Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version!Consider adding "pragma solidity ^0.4.6
contract Add {
^
Spanning multiple lines.
Compilation failed. See above.
fs.js:549`

Then i add compile version like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
contract Add {

    function Add() {
    }

    function sum(uint x, uint y) returns (uint) {
        return (x+y);
    }
}
```

And now it pass the compile. But this time I got the error:

`cp: no such file or directory: ./../originalContracts/Migrations.sol
rm: no such file or directory: ./allFiredEvents
Compiling Add.sol...
  Contract: Add
    ✓ should return 5 when add 2 and 3
  1 passing (15s)
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './allFiredEvents'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/maiffany/graduate/mytest/solcover/runCoveredTests.js:60:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)`

And in the runCoveredTests.js I found this:

`55:shell.cp("./../originalContracts/Migrations.sol",./../contracts/Migrations.sol");
56:
57:shell.rm('./allFiredEvents'); //Delete previous results
58:shell.exec('truffle test --network coverage');
59:
60:events = fs.readFileSync('./allFiredEvents').toString().split('\n')`

I guess maybe it is this command that generate file "allFiredEvents". So i try this in my command line:

`truffle test --network coverage
Compiling Add.sol...
  Contract: Add
    ✓ should return 5 when add 2 and 3
  1 passing (24s)`

But i still can't find the file "allFiredEvents".

So where did i get wrong?

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks cgewecke and area! https://github.com/JoinColony/solcover/issues/17